# How to Connect SharePoint Online to SQL On Prem?

Tags: sharepoint-online, odata

Has anyone successfully connected SharePoint Online or O365 to a SQL on prem server? If yes, a detailed how would be lovely.

Comment: you want to connect SharePoint OnLine to an SQL Server like External Content using BDC (Business Data Connectivity)???

Comment: You can also manipulate data of SQL Server via javascript (by calling webservices) or you can build a SharePoint app. You should give us more details on what are your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (in my opinion)

Is to create a REST service that communicates with your SQL database,
And from there make REST calls to your service in javascript, using [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895.aspx) as an example.

You should also read [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103917/can-local-sql-server-data-be-made-available-in-sharepoint-online), which is a similar question to yours

Comment: I heard that there was an OData WCF Service way?