# How to integrate local SQL db with Sharepoint online office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have a requirement in Office 365, SharePoint Online where we want to integrate it with local on-premise SQL database.

We will have a form which will directly insert the date into SQL db from SharePoint Online.

Please suggest the necessary actions that I have to perform or possible solutions.

Comment: This may help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103917/can-local-sql-server-data-be-made-available-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 1):

You can take the advantage of the BCS services.BCS is supported with Office 365 Enterprise E3 and E4 plan. SharePoint Online only supports WCF and SQL Server Azure Connectors for Business Data Connectivity Services. thats mean you have a SQL azure instance and sync it with on prem SQL and Sharepoint.

For a detailed guide, you may refer to the

[[Make an External List](http://Make%20an%20External%20List%20from%20a%20SQL%20Azure%20table%20with%20Business%20Connectivity%20Services%20and%20Secure%20Store) from a [SQL Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-provision-sql-server/) table with Business Connectivity Services and Secure Store][1](http://Make%20an%20External%20List%20from%20a%20SQL%20Azure%20table%20with%20Business%20Connectivity%20Services%20and%20Secure%20Store)

[Connect SharePoint Online to an on-premises SQL Server from an Azure provider hosted app using Hybrid Connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2014/07/31/connect-sharepoint-online-to-an-on-premises-sql-server-from-an-azure-provider-hosted-app-using-hybrid-connections.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively easy to use BCS - just make sure you open the SQL port and make it publicly available to sharepoint and add necessary security around it.
the second one done my alimaz is useless don't even waste your time - it has many bugs and costs you $65 + per month!!